# SWT incorrectly detects key combinations

Tags: java, swt, windows-10

I have two languages on my Windows 10 (english and russian). I run the following code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setSize(640, 480);
    shell.setLocation(500, 250);
    shell.setText("SWT");

    FillLayout layout = new FillLayout();
    shell.setLayout(layout);

    shell.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
            if ((e.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) != 0) {
                keys.add("Ctrl");
            }
            if ((e.stateMask & SWT.ALT) != 0) {
                keys.add("Alt");
            }
            if ((e.stateMask & SWT.SHIFT) != 0) {
                keys.add("Shift");
            }
            keys.add(Character.toString((char) e.keyCode));
            System.out.println(keys);
        }
    });

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }

    display.dispose();
}
```

When the language is set to english and I press `Right Alt + T`, the program correctly prints `[Alt, t]`.

However, when I switch the language to russian and press `Right Alt+T`, the program prints `[Ctrl, Alt, t]`. This is incorrect because I didn't press Ctrl.

This is annoying because our Eclipse RCP key bindings (such as `Alt+F7` or `Alt+Shift+F5`) do not work correctly.

Any ideas why SWT incorrectly detects `Ctrl`?

I'm using SWT from the latest Eclipse 4.6 (SWT 3.105.0).

Comment: have you checked https://www.eclipse.org/swt/bugs.php ?

Comment: Are you sure you are not using the `AltGr` button (right `Alt`) instead of the standard `Alt` button (left `Alt`)? It seems that the interpretation of `AltGr` is closely connected to the keyboard layout.

Comment: @LorisSecuro Yes, I'm using Right Alt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For historical reasons, the `AltGr` (right `Alt`) key used in non-US keyboard layouts is automatically converted by the operating system as `Ctrl + Alt` ([see Wikipedia about this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key#Control_.2B_Alt_as_a_substitute)).

So this is not specifically related to `SWT`.

To avoid this problem users should just use the standard `Alt` (left `Alt`) key.

Comment: I cannot tell the customers just not to use the Right Alt. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried disabling shortcut to change language in windows 10.